# How can I pass a ruby(rails) variable into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

This is an app in rails.

Here's what I have in 'routes':

```
 resources :destinations
```

Here is what I have in 'destinations_controller':

```
def show
     @destination = Destination.find(params[:id])
end
```

Here's what I have in 'views/destinations/show.html.erb':

```
<h2><%= @destination.latitude %></h2>

<script>

    var dest_lat = <%= @destination.latitude %>

</script>
```

Here's what I have in 'application.js':

```
var dest_location = {dest_lat};
```

This is the third time I've built this app.  Initially, I get no errors and all the coding works fine... for a few hours.  Then, without me changing anything, the value in @destination.latitude still appears in the h2 tag, but I start to receive the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dest_lat is not defined
```

with a link that shows its use in 'application.js', and the app ceases to work.

Why?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's likely that `@destination.latitude` is not outputting anything.

Comment: Or that application.js is being loaded before the on page script is evaluated, depending on where the two scripts tags are relative to each other on he page.

Comment: @evolutionxbox   '@destination.latitude' definitely outputs something.  I have it in an h2 in the same show page and that prints out fine.  It only breaks when it runs through the js.

Comment: @paul Improper loading order would be my guess.  How might I fix that?

Comment: What console errors are you getting?

Comment: Just what I mentioned above: that "dest_lat is not defined", repeated for every function I use dest_lat in.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't printing something useful for Javascript:

```
<script>
    var dest_lat = <%= @destination.latitude %>
</script>
```

Try instead to change it to:

```
<script>
    var dest_lat = '<%= @destination.latitude %>';
</script>
```

Here you can see that the quotes make the difference.

```js
var dest_lat = some_value;
```

```js
var dest_lat = 'some_value';
console.log(dest_lat);
```

Update: To make your data available in your application.js you can store them in a non-visible div, with content_tag, which will content your `@destination.latitude` and anything else you need to work

```
# your_view.html.erb
<%= content_tag :div, class: 'destination_latitude', data: {destination_latitude: @destination.latitude} do %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can access to them as a Javascript object:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  console.log($('.destination_latitude').data('destination-latitude'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Unfortunately, I tried what you said and nothing changed.

Comment: I looked at gon briefly.  I would really rather avoid throwing yet another gem into the mix, especially since what I'm doing theoretically shouldn't require a gem.

Answer (score 1):

Check your rendered HTML output.  As I said in my comment, I'm guessing that the script tag with the src pointing at your javascript file(s) is being called before the script tag with the embedded javascript.  The fix is to just change the order that they're declared on the page, but the specifics will depend on how your layouts, pages, and partials are setup (which I can't tell from your posted question).

When all is said and done, you'll have something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  // Your embedded script
</script>
<script src='/path/to/application.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

in your rendered output.